# How can I make an element sticky in a FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a certain area occupied by FlatList.

I need to "attach" a line of text to the bottom of a list.

To

**1**: text was at the bottom of the list when there were few elements in the list;

**2**: the text was as if the last element if it did not fit on the screen

I've been trying to achieve this for a long time(
In CSS I would just do `display: sticky`, but this is not possible here(

---

I am attaching a sketch that describes what I am trying to achieve.

Red is the container around the list (or the list itself - it doesn’t matter).
Blue - list elements.
Green is the line of text that I want to pin.

[image]